# Перемещение окна за курсором с помощью библиотеки pyglet

Tags: python, python-3.x

Мне нужно, чтобы окно программы двигалось за курсором мыши или хотя бы просто перемещалось. Я использую функцию `pyglet.window.Window.set_location(x, y)` для назначения следующего местоположения окна и функцию `pyglet.window.Window.flip()` для обновления окна. Для примера, вместо координат курсора создаю цикл `for` с растущей переменной `x`. 
Выглядит это примерно вот так:

```py
window = pyglet.window.Window()
for i in range(1000):
    window.set_location(i, 500)
    window.flip()
```

В итоге, после нескольких секунд окно зависает и Windows предлагает завершить процесс. Я думаю ошибка в неправильном использовании мной функции `window.flip()`, но другого способа я не нашел.

Comment: у меня есть вопрос, может не совсем в тему, но: для чего вам это?

Comment: @n1tr0xs, скорее всего, глупо делать это подобным способом, но я хочу попробовать сделать что-то похожее на недавно вышедшее приложение "goose desktop", где гусь бегает по экрану и совершает всякие действия.

Answer (score 0):

Вот код, который создает окно и перемещает его к мышке при ее движение внутри него.

```
import pyglet
window=pyglet.window.Window()

@window.event
def on_mouse_motion(x, y, dx ,dy):
    window.set_location(x,y)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Это не совсем то, чего я хочу добиться. Я хочу, чтобы окно двигалось не зависимо от того, где находится курсор. То есть курсор не обязательно в самом окне находится. Я примерно придумал как это сделать, но после нескольких секунд окно зависает по неизвестным причинам.

Comment: Я понял, что окно зависает из-за того, что цикл ```for``` кончается. Тогда как реализовать перемещение окна в игровом цикле? Под игровым циклом я имею в виду ```pyglet.app.run()```.