# Окно следует за указателем мыши

Tags: python, pyqt5, mousepressevent, mousemoveevent

Можно ли как-то реализовать на Пайтоне, чтобы при нажатии и удерживании курсора на окне, оно двигалось за курсором?

Если да, то какие библиотеки для этого использовать?

Comment: Можент быть Вам подойдет [эта статья](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1077223/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8-pyglet)

Comment: @Artem L. это немного не то. в Вашем примере окно убегает от курсора, а мне нужно как-то привязать координаты окна до координат курсора.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint


class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        # ...
        
# !!! vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.oldPos = event.globalPos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
       delta = QPoint(event.globalPos() - self.oldPos)
       self.move(self.x() + delta.x(), self.y() + delta.y())
       self.oldPos = event.globalPos()
# !!! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyApp()
    w.resize(400, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]